# pl sql select внутри if

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

компилятор ругается на участок в функции, как выполнить подзапрос с сохранением результата в переменную в участке else?

```
if Cnt > 0 Then
   tmpVal:='ZERO';
else
    select myVal into tmpVal from mytable where rownum =1;
end if;
```

Comment: Как именно у вас ругается компилятор ?

Comment: Error: PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
Line: 44
Text: END IF;

Comment: обнаружил ошибку после вашего комментария, забыл ; после окончания select в своем коде

Comment: @Paul А что такое Cnt ? Я там коммент под ответом написал, потому что то решение не всегда применимо. Если ваша проблема была в общем то только в точке с запятой я бы все оставил как есть. А вопрос удалил, так как он был вызван опечаткой.

Comment: @Mike Cnt переменная, которая хранит в себе количество записей, полученное из другого запроса.Именно в опечатке и была проблема, удалить вопрос система не позволяет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN Cnt > 0 THEN 'ZERO'
                         ELSE myVal 
       END INTO tmpVal 
FROM mytable 
WHERE rownum =1;
```